# Синхронизация проекта Visual Studio и репозитория

Tags: git

сделал на локальном репозитории git reset --hard до определённого коммита, потом git push, но в проекте Visual Studio остались некоторые файлы, которых уже нет в репозиториях. Как мне эти файлы удалить?

Comment: `git clean -xdf`, удалит все файлы, которых нет в индексе. Делайте на свой страх и риск.

Comment: все поломалося, но я удалил папки с проекта и сделал git clone. Сработало на первый взгляд...